# How to configure publication key permanently in public instance of magnolia?

Tags: magnolia

I am very new to magnolia for publishing the content from author to public. I am facing the below problem.

I am configuring activation key from author instance of magnolia to all public instances.

When ever I am restarting the author instance again I need to generate the new key manually and set the key to all public instances.

Is there any way to set that activation key of author instance to all public instances permanently ?

Answer (score 1):

For non-development systems it's best practice to store the key with an absolute path outside of the web application, like /opt/magnolia/config/keypair.properties.

This path is referenced automatically from all the instances using this key if you apply the correct configuration file (see also https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/WAR+file+with+multiple+configurations).

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a properties file with no key only the value. In the default-magnolia.properties you can set the property "magnolia.author.key.location" to the location of that file.

Comment: even though the public key is same after restarting the server i am unable to publish. Again i have to generate a new key and configure that to publish. The following error I am getting  **activation/deactivation failed
 java.lang.securityException
 private key doesn't exist**